# Prevent replacing \n in JavaScript when using String.replace()

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, replace

The problem is that .replace method behave unexpectedly.
I have a large string variable with special characters, so I show you a small example:

```js
let str = "a \n b \/\ c";  
str.replace('a','z');  
console.log(str)
// expecting str: "z \n b \/\ c"  
// but the result str is :   
// "z  
//  b / c"
```

How can I replace some characters and prevent the modification of other special characters?
For your information, I have a large JS file (codes), which I need to replace some variables, so I've put the code between `` and create a string and use string.replace() for desired result.
But the result removes all \n and /\ and other special characters.

Comment: You don't understand the strings you wrote. [A little article about escape sequences](https://bestprogrammingblogs.blogspot.com/2020/07/javascript-escape-sequences.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.raw` with a template literal so that all characters inside are interpreted *completely literally*:

```js
let str = String.raw`a \n b \/\ c`;
console.log(str.replace('a','z'));
```

But backticks will have to be escaped too, using this method, if you're just pasting plain code into your JS.

A better method would be to provide an interface for the code to be input, so that you don't have to deal with any escaping issues yourself:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.onchange = () => {
  console.log(textarea.value.replace('a', 'z'));
};
```

```html
<textarea>a \n b \/\ c</textarea>
```

Another option is to put the raw JS code you're changing into a `<script>` tag:

```js
const str = document.querySelector('script[type="to-be-replaced"]').textContent;
console.log(str.replace('a','z'));
```

```html
<script type="to-be-replaced">a \n b \/\ c</script>
```